# How to test state update with dispatch function of useReducer after get request?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am trying to understand the logic of how to write unit tests. But i am stuck in here. I have a simple product listing page and it sends requests based on filtering options and returns related products. `getProducts` function pulls related products and updates my global state. How can i test this? How should be the logic?

###### getProducts Function

```
  const getProducts = async () => {
    const { color, brand, sort, search, page } = state;
    const URL = `/api/v1/products?page=${page}&color=${color}&brand=${brand}&sort=${sort}&search=${search}`;
    dispatch({ type: SETUP_PRODUCTS_BEGIN });
    try {
      const { data } = await axios(URL);
      dispatch({
        type: SETUP_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS,
        payload: {
          products: data.products,
          colorOptions: data.colorOptions,
          brandOptions: data.brandOptions,
          numOfPages: data.numOfPages,
        },
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

###### Reducer

```
if (action.type === SETUP_PRODUCTS_BEGIN) {
    return { ...state, isLoading: true };
}
if (action.type === SETUP_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS) {
  return {
    ...state,
    isLoading: false,
    products: action.payload.products,
    colorOptions: action.payload.colorOptions,
    brandOptions: action.payload.brandOptions,
    numOfPages: action.payload.numOfPages,
  };
}
```

###### initialState

```
const initialState = {
  products: [],
  isLoading: false,
  colorOptions: null,
  brandOptions: null,
  numOfPages: null,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too general.

You have mentioned two components in your question:

1. Product list React Component
2. A redux state with some reducers

In order to unit-test components, you need to be able to control all the external dependencies. All your code component/modules should have only one responsibility.

Let's analyze what you have:
Your UI component has too much knowledge - it knows how to get data from the back end, and it even knows the path of the API. Your component has to know how to render based on props/redux state and what actions to dispatch on certain events.

Unfortunately, if you use useDispathc and useElector redux hooks which menans you always have to test your component along with a redux state.

Here are my recomendations. (examples are using `jest`)

1. You need to unit test your reducer(s). Since they are pure javascript functions - we do not need to mock anything

```
import reducer from "/path-to-the-reducer";

describe("Action SETUP_PRODUCTS_BEGIN", () => {
  it("Should set isLoading to true nomatter what", () => {
    //setup
    const initialState = { abc: "Germany", isLoading: undefined };

    //act
    cons resultState = reducer(initialState, { type: SETUP_PRODUCTS_BEGIN });

    //assert
    expect(resultState.isLoading).toBe(true);
  });
})
```

2. In order to test your component you need two things:

2.1 Separate the rest api call into a separate module. In this case you will allow other UI components to reuse same logic for the API calls. This is very basic example:

***RestApi.js***

```
const listProducts = async (input) => {
  const { color, brand, sort, search, page } = input;
  const URL = `/api/v1/products?page=${page}&color=${color}&brand=${brand}&sort=${sort}&search=${search}`;
  const axiosResult = await axios(URL);
  return axios.data;
}
```

2.2 You need to use a library to test you react component. As of writing this post react recommends ***React testing library*** [React testing](https://reactjs.org/docs/testing.html).

So you need to do a few things:

- mock the RestApi methods you need
- mock the redux state and "listen for dispatches"
- ensure your component renders correct things based on the props/reduxState

I will post some pseudo javascript code to how it should look

```js
import { listProducts } from './restAPI'

//mockign the listProducts to return empty array each time
jest.mock('./restAPI', () => ({
  listProducts : () => Promise.resolve([]),
}))


describe("Component initialization ", async () => {
  it("Should call SETUP_PRODUCTS_BEGIN and SETUP_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS on componend load", () => {
    /// configureStore from the @reduxjs/toolkit npm package
    const store = configureStore({ reducer: {}, { isLoading: true, products: [] } })
    const renderResult = await render(<Provider store={store}><ProductListComponent /></Provider>);

   //assert
   const actions = store.getActions();

   expect(actions).toHaveLength(2);
   expect(actions[0].type).toEqual("SETUP_PRODUCTS_BEGIN");
   expect(actions[1].type).toEqual("SETUP_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS");
  });
});
```

[Redux in unit testing](https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-tests)